# javax.naming.CommunicationException:

Tags: jboss, ejb

I have created a helloworld app in EJB 3.0 with Jboss 6 as given in in below link

http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/ejb3/how-to-create-a-simple-ejb3-project-in-eclipse-jboss-6-1/

Now I am getting below exception I have done a lot of rnd about it but i couldnt found it as i am new to EJB please help.

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

****javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:1099 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out]****
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.discoverServer(NamingContext.java:1690)

```
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1761)


at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:695)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:688)

at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)


at com.ibytecode.client.EJBApplicationClient.doLookup(EJBApplicationClient.java:22)
at com.ibytecode.client.EJBApplicationClient.main(EJBApplicationClient.java:10)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out

at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(Unknown Source)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(Unknown Source)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.discoverServer(NamingContext.java:1659)
... 6 more

[Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server
```

localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException:

Failed to connect to server localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]]]

```
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1780)

at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:695)

at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:688)

at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)

at com.ibytecode.client.EJBApplicationClient.doLookup(EJBApplicationClient.java:22)
at com.ibytecode.client.EJBApplicationClient.main(EJBApplicationClient.java:10)
```

Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]]

```
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:337)

at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1746)
... 5 more
```

Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:307)
    ... 6 more

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

```
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)

at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:97)
at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:82)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:303)
... 6 more
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibytecode.client.EJBApplicationClient.main(EJBApplicationClient.java:12)

Answer (score -1):

You have a Nullpointer at EJBApplicationClient.java:12

Comment: this response suits better as a comment